# SystemPropertiesAdvanced.exe permission denied

Tags: windows-10, permissions

Since today I can't access SystemPropertiesAdvanced anymore (Changing PATH variables).

When I go to the Start menu and type "Variables" and select the first result, which is "Edit system ambient variables", it just pops up an error:

[image: Windows cannot access the device, path or file specified. Maybe you don't have adequate permissions to access this item]
*Windows cannot access the device, path or file specified. Maybe you don't have adequate permissions to access this item*

If I go inside `C:/Windows/system32/`, the file `SystemPropertiesAdvanced.exe` exists and can be opened normally, and I can change variables.

Searching for a solution, someone on a Microsoft Support page said that it could be "WinDir" that's not in the Path/Registry anymore. After checking, it is.

[image: windir has value '%SystemRoot%']

I also tried `Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth` in hope it would fix this. It didn't.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Run [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html). If nothing is found you might need to [Repair Install of Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html).